Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{100}$ be hundred integers such that the sum of any five of them is $20$. What can be concluded from this?
The problem has options $a)$ the largest $x_{i}$ equals $5$. $b)$ the smallest $x_{i}$ is $3$. $c)$ $x_{17}=x_{83}$ and $d)$ none of the statements are true.
I have done this problem by taking two different sums of 5 numbers $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{17}= x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{83}=20$. Now the common terms cancel out and we get that $x_{17}=x_{83}$. Is this the correct way to solve the problem?

From where did you get this problem?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

I read the title but I still don't understand the question. What is auk?

@Gribouillis that is a typo, it’s any.

By your argument all the numbers are equal (to 4).

Yes @ParamanandSingh , I also see that but I am unsure whether it’s true or not.

Its correct argument because given any two numbers in this list we can select 4 others and add them to get 20 on both sides. Thus any two are equal and that means all are equal.

[[1]] "What can be concluded from this ?" All numbers are Equal to $4$ , hence Option D is right. [[2]] "Which Option is true ?" Option C is true , though it is arbitrary to claim that in general.

I am trying to convey that when we are asked "what is the conclusion ?" then the sane conclusion is "D none of these" , @YvesDaoust , while when we are asked "which is true here ?" then "C is indeed true" , which is highly arbitrary & narrow !

Someone might find a better answer, but.....
Consider I have taken five numbers from the first,
$$
x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5
$$
and keeping $x_5$ common, I choose another four numbers from the list:
$$
x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9
$$
Their sum is the same, which means:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=x_6+x_7+x_8+x_9$$
Moreover, let's choose the second set of five numbers in such a way that, both $x_5$ and $x_4$ is common, then, our second set of numbers is:
$$x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8$$
Their summation is the sum, which concludes:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=x_6+x_7+x_8$$
Subtracting this from the previous equation, you can show $x_4=x_6$. Thus, with every $100$ integers, taking each of them in pairs, you can show that they are equal to one another. You can also show that $x_1=x_{100}$, but it will take a long time, since it will need you to prove that $x_1=x_2$, then $x_2=x_3$ and then all the way up to $x_{99}=x_{100}$.
Therefore, the only accurate answer here is $x_{17}=x_{83}$.
Edit:
I seem to have made the answer a bit more lengthy than necessary. My apologies. I just tried to explain my point of view regarding my answer of the question.

I think there's a typo because you say "choose the second set of five numbers" but then list six. You didn't use $x_9$. Also when you "subtract from the previous equation", you should get $x_4 = x_9$.

@AdamDougall Edited it. Thanks for finding

From
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 20$$
and
$$x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 20$$
we conclude (subtract one equation from the other) that $x_1 = x_6$.  It's easy to see that this argument generalizes to any $x_i$ and $x_j$, so $x_i = x_j$ for all $i$ and $j$.

To make the generalization as compact as possible, one could replace $x_6\to x_j$ with $j\neq 1$. Then immediately $x_j=x_1$ and thus all are equal.

I assume the $x_i$ in any sum need to be distinct. Otherwise trivially $5 x_i = 20$. In which case you'd have $j \neq 1,2,3,4,5$ and so you'd still need to show $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5$.

Up to reordering, we can assume $x_1 \le ... \le x_{100}$. In particular, $x_1 \le x_{100}$, $x_2 \le x_{99}$, $x_3 \le x_{98}$, $x_4 \le x_{97}$ and $x_5 \le x_{96}$. Summing the inequalities, we find $$x_1 + ... + x_5 \le x_{96} + ... + x_{100}$$ which is strict if and only if one of the starting inequalities is strict. But by assumption, this inequality is an equality, hence the five initial inequalities are equalities. In particular, $x_1 = x_{100}$, and since we ordered the $x_i$ by size, they are all equal (hence to 4). So only c) is true.
Notice that this holds regardless of the $x_i$ being integers or real numbers, and works as soon as there are at least 6 such numbers $x_i$.
